# Using xpath to locate an element and click on it

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium with java, Can not click on button. How to use xpath to locate an element and click on it?

Here is part of source page which I am using:

```
<div id="top-navigation">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="item first active">
<a href="/index.php/sprachen-lernen/englisch">Home</a></li>
<li class="item ">
<a href="/index.php/openArea/school">Online Language School
                </a></li>
<li class="item ">
<a href="/index.php/openArea/partner">Enterprise Solutions
                </a></li>
<li class="item ">
<a href="/index.php/openArea/customer">References
                </a></li>
<li class="item last ">
<a href="/index.php/openArea/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
    <div id="login-button">
                    <a href="/login/login"><img src="/images/openArea/login.png" alt="Login" /></a>
            </div>
</div>
```

Here is statement I am using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
```

But it does not click on the button.This is my first effort with selenium so can someone please guide me that is wrong with my statement or if I want to use xpath then what should be the exact statement

Answer (score 0):

I have used firebug to locate the xpath of element and now it works :)